# How to properly update the kernel

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom

According to [this](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211) page, the BCM43340 Broadcom chipset is supported in kernel 4.0+. After booting this kernel on a machine, the network card was still not detected.

On the other hand, it seems that the firmware for the network card is provided by `linux-firmware`:

```
 $ dpkg -S /lib/firmware/brcm/b*
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43242a.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43569.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
```

How should I properly update the kernel, so that I get the support for the network card? Is there a version of `linux-firmware` which matches the 4.1.2 kernel

**EDIT:** I have a newer 4.1.2 kernel, built against Trusty (it's older, so it should be no problem)
I modprobe'd `brcmfmac` and these are the mentions of `brcm`

```
$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    4.263584] brcmf_sdio_drivestrengthinit: No SDIO Drive strength init done for chip 43340 rev 2 pmurev 20
[    4.267389] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.278197] brcmfmac_sdio mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin failed with error -2
[    7.287580] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[    8.296113] brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

The `brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin` firmware piece is missing:

```
$ find /lib -name brcmfmac*
/lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmfmac
/lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
/lib/modules/3.19.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmfmac
/lib/modules/3.19.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
```

`brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin` seems to be in `linux-firmware` 1.146 (from Wily) but I'm not sure if I can so simply install a random package on Wily, being on Vivid.

As asked,

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; uname -r
4.1.2-040102-generic
```

Comment: If your issue is a wireless adapter, please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: Is that an internal or a usb device?

Comment: Internal. Other users managed to get it working by manually building the kernel. But I'd rather use the official Ubuntu versions

Comment: You can install `linux-firmware` from wily. It is just a set of firmware files. There may be come incompatibilities, but it is unlikely. And it looks like you have already kernel 4.1 installed.

Comment: Yes, but 4.1 was built against trusty, see http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.2-unstable/BUILT
What incompatibilities can I expect and why should they not happen?

Comment: You can install the required firmware file independently: `cd /lib/firmware/brcm` and then: `sudo wget http://ftp2.halpanet.org/source/_dev/linux-firmware.git/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin` Unload and reload the driver: `sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac && sudo modprobe brcmfmac` and check the logs again: `dmesg | grep brcm`. Reference: http://ftp2.halpanet.org/source/_dev/linux-firmware.git/brcm/

Comment: What do you mean by "built against trusty". It is just a kernel mainline image. Some firmware files or directories may be renamed with a new kernel. But it happens not very often and it is very unlikely you have that hardware.

Answer (score 0):

First, find your architecture:

```
arch
```

You will probably find either x86_64; that is, 64-bit, or else i386; that is, 32-bit. If it is otherwise, post back and we'll advise.

Go here to download the kernel packages: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.9-wily/

If yours is, as I suspect, a 64-bit system, download to your desktop linux-headers-generic-xx-amd64.deb, linux-headers-xx-all.deb and linux-image-xx-amd64.deb.

Now install them from the terminal with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/linux*.deb
```

After a reboot, confirm you are running the new 4.0-xx kernel:

```
uname -r
```

It ought to return: `4.0.9-040009-generic`.

Load the presumed driver:

```
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

Check the log for messages:

```
dmesg | grep brcm
```

Comment: please see the edit of OP